# Adwords : Converting Non-API based Adwords account to API based Adwords account

Tags: google-ads-api

Currently we have a non-API based adwords account and we plan to move to an API based ad-words account; can the below be done in order to preserve the account history?
1> Is it possible to change a non-API account to an API account (for the purpose of preserving the account history)
2> If we create a new API account, can it be linked to the existing non-API account so that the history of 2 accounts are tied - in that case, we can have 2 separate accounts without compromising on the historical data

Thanks,
-Dev

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a concept of "API-based" vs. "non API-based" accounts in AdWords. They're all created equal, and you may use different tools (including API) to interact with your account. Using API with your account should not affect it in any way.